# Предупреждение "class X должен иметь dll-интерфейс для использования клиентами class Y"

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, lambda

Здравствуйте. Продолжаю постигать хитросплетения С++. На этот раз решил попробовать написать уже динамическую библиотеку (то есть .dll) для упрощенной работы с GUI Windows. Все классы и необходимые функции экспортируются - `__declspec(dllexport)`. Все было хорошо, но дело в том что у меня во многих классах по задумке должны быть атрибуты отвечающие за различные события, они в виде лямбд (например `std::function<void()> onPaint_` и прочие). И вот когда я добавил лямбды как атрибуты своего класса - стали появляться warning'и при компиляции. А именно вот такого содержания:

> class "std::function" должен иметь dll-интерфейс для использования клиентами class "wquery::Window"

Не совсем понимаю в чем суть и что имеется в виду? Лямба, это ведь по сути объект шаблонного класса (или я ошибаюсь)? То есть я не могу использовать в интерфейсе какие-то сторонние объекты, у которых.. нет..  `__declspec(dllexport)` в их классах? Или что? Это потому-что.. на той платформе, где будет использоваться .dll, классы этих объектов могут быть не теми что используются при ее сборке? В этом дело? Но как тогда правильно подойти к этой задаче?

Я попробовал использовать указатель (то есть `std::function<void()>* onPaint_`), тогда варнинги исчезают, возникает другая проблема - как обратиться к лямбде как к функции (чтобы вызвать ее), когда у меня есть только указатель на объект лямбды? То есть если раньше я мог делать вот так - `window->onPaint_()`, то теперь такое, понятное дело, не срабатывает. Я пытался делать что-то вот такое - `*(window->onPaint_)()`, но компилятор на это тоже ругается.

В общем хотелось бы понять, как лучше подойти к этому всему. Может быть я делаю что-то в корне не правильное? За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::function<void()>` это ни разу не лямбда. Если требуется использовать этот класс в интерфейсе библиотеки то его придется экспортировать из библиотеки иначе в библиотеке и использующем ее коде будет рассинхрон. Класс можно экспортировать явно инстанцировав его указав спецификатор экспорта:

```
 template class DLL_API ::std::function<void (void)>;
```

где `DLL_API` - `__declspec(dllexport)` или `__declspec(dllimport)`